# fsolve - mismatch between input and output

Tags: python, excel, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to solve an overdetmined system of equations with three unknowns. I'm able to get solution with fsolve and lsqnonlin in MATLAB by calling the system of equations through a for loop.

But in python using scipy, I'm getting the following error message:

```
fsolve: there is a mismatch between the input and output shape of the 'func' argument 'fnz'
```

The code is given below:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
g = [0.5,1,1.5]
wb = open_workbook('EThetaValuesA.xlsx')
sheet=wb.sheet_by_index(0)
y=sheet.col_values(0,1)
t1=sheet.col_values(1,1)
t2=sheet.col_values(2,1)
t3=sheet.col_values(3,1)

def fnz(g):
    i=0
    sol=[0 for i in range(len(t1))]
    x1 = g[0]
    x2 = g[1]
    x3 = g[2]
    print len(t1)
    for i in range(len(t1)):
        # various set of t1,t2 and t3 gives the various eqns
        print i
        sol[i]=x1+t1[i]/(x2*t2[i]+x3*t3[i])-y[i]    
    return sol

Anz = optimize.fsolve(fnz,g)

print Anz
```

Could anyone please suggest where I'm wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The exception means that the result from `fnz()` function call does not has the same dimension as the input `g`, which is a list of 3 elements, or can be seen as an `array` of shape `(3,)`.

To illustrate the problem, if we define:

```
def fnz(g):
    return [2,3,5]
Anz = optimize.fsolve(fnz,g)
```

There will not be such an exception. But this will:

```
def fnz(g):
    return [2,3,4,5]
Anz = optimize.fsolve(fnz,g)
```

The result from `fnz()` should have the same length as `t1`, which I am sure is longer than 3 elements.

Comment: Here g contains initial guess values that x1,x2 and x3 should take. I have given like that because scipy.optimize.fsolve(func, x0, args=(), fprime=None, full_output=0, col_deriv=0, xtol=1.49012e-08, maxfev=0, band=None, epsfcn=0.0, factor=100, diag=None, warning=True)

Comment: I changed the function output to length(t1). But it gives bit weird results for x1,x2, and x3. The results I was getting in MATLAB using a similar code as above gave an accurate answer. Is it something which I need to change in the code(to make the python code similar to MATLAB code on a functional level).